# Does get_defined_vars() show variables defined in variable_set()?

Tags: 6, configuration

I'm using Drupal 6, and I'm having problems retrieving a set of variables I set with `variable_set()` using `variable_get()`. I'm doing a `dpr(get_defined_vars())` to see what's defined, and I don't see my variables; I see only the arrays `$form` and `$form_state` (this is inside `hook_submit()`).

Does `get_defined_vars()` show all the variables defined via `variable_get()`/`variable_set()`? I would just like to see a list of all of them. I just need to see if they've been set correctly, and troubleshoot why I can't retrieve them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) is a PHP function, not a Drupal function.  It basically shows you all variables that are in scope.

Drupal variables set by [variable_set](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/6) are not automatically within scope.

Variables are stored in `global $conf;` but I don't recall if non-variables are also stored here.

If you install the [Devel Module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) there is a page for viewing and editing variables.

EDIT:

Curiosity got to me.  The variable editor in the Devel Module queries the `{variable}` table and not `global $conf;` to build the form of all available variables, so that suggests that is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you set with `variable_set()` are called "Drupal variables," or "persistent variables." They are not PHP variables, and `get_defined_vars()` doesn't return them.

During bootstrap, the content of the "variables" table is copied into the global variable `$conf` that contains also values set in settings.php, such as the string overrides.

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
  'forum'      => 'Discussion board',
  '@count min' => '@count minutes',
);
```

If you want to verify which Drupal variables are set, then you can use the global variable `$conf`, but I would suggest to do it only for debugging purposes, and not in code that you publicly distribute or use outside a test site.